# android rotation returning wrong values

Tags: java, android

I am properly handling rotation on android using onconfigurationchanges event. When event is fired, new orientation is returned as desired. However, layout has also a webview that has fill_parent property and is scaled according it when rotation.

Problem is that webview sometimes returns opposite size value (when portrait returns landscape dimensions and viceversa), probably because it is not being resized yet when size request. How to handle then that device ends configuration changes?? Thank you.

```
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {

      super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);  

      if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) { 
            //Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
              int heightW = webviewA.getHeight();
              Toast.makeText(this, Integer.toString(heightW), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } else{
            //Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
              int heightW = webviewA.getHeight();
            Toast.makeText(this, Integer.toString(heightW), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


   }
```